# Problems with backup/restore compiz settings

Tags: compiz, settings

The problem I am having is that some of my compiz settings are lost after a reboot. I am using 13.04 and Unity.

The problem is with the **focus-follows-mouse**, **auto-raise** and **auto-raise-delay** setting.

After a reboot my system forgets about ffm and reverts it back to default click on focus. I exported a working compiz config from another machine (where it works fine) and wanted to import the settings file to the system with the bug but in the compiz backup config there is no ffm setting included and compiz enables the default values.

So how could I solve this issue? Before I do a bug report I wanted to ask here for help if someone knows a work around this situation.

Comment: I, too, experience this problem on one machine running 13.04.  On two other machines that were running 13.04 I do not experience this problem.

Comment: It seems that no one knows anything about this :/